# How to generate buttons dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have one table with some records. My table like this

```
WFID clientID WorkflowName      workflowsteps                    completedstep 
12     15       print       cutting,printing,lamination             -
```

Workflowsteps will vary depending upon the workflow name.

In `completedstep` column it will show the completed steps. For example: if cutting and printing is done then it will show cutting,printing

Now I want to create dynamic buttons with the name cutting, printing, lamination
All the button will be disable by default only first button will be enable and clickable if I press first button "cutting" then its color should changed to red and  The next "printing" button will be enable. Same process will repeat for each dynamic button.

How to do this in ASP.net?
:)

Comment: Seems like a straight forward question, why the negatives?

Answer (score 0):

Put cutting button inside completedstep column.Do your code in gridviewrowcreated event, and enable only first button.Keep a printing button their also after cutting button make it visible false.Create a cuttingbuttonclick event handler method to handle visibility of printing button.

For dynamic button place a panel or placeholder inside grid.Then create button from codebehind and add it to the panel or placeholder.
Put this code inside gridviewrowcreated event.

```
Panel panel1=(Panel)e.Row.FindControl("PanelinsideGrid");
Button dynbtn = new Button();
dynbtn.Text = "Button Name";
panel1.Controls.Add(dynbtn)
```